# Angularjs accessing form in controller(todolist)?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a to-do list in angular js. I am trying to access the form in the controller. However, when I click the add new button, it doesn't add to the list.

There is also no error displaying which shows to me that the function probably isn't doing anything.

How do I get the add new button to add to the list.

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   lang="en">
<head>
    <h1>To do List</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl as vm">


<form name="vm.myform" ng-submit="toDoAdd()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="vm.toDoAdd " value="Add New">

    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done"><span ng-bind="x.todoText">
    </span>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button ng-click="remove()">Remove marked</button></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('todoCtrl',['$scope' ,function ($scope) {
    $scope.toDoList = [{todoText: "check", done: false}];

    function todoAdd() {
        var vm=this;
        vm.toDoAdd=toDoAdd;
        $scope.toDoAdd = function () {
            $scope.toDoList.push({todoText: $scope.todoInput, done: false});
            $scope.todoInput = "";
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Bests practice avoids mixing `this` based html with `$scope` based html.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your application:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="toDoAdd()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
      <input type="submit" value="Add New">
      <br>
      <div ng-repeat="x in toDoList">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done" /><span ng-bind="x.todoText">
      </span>
      </div>
      <p>
      <button type="button" ng-click="remove()">Remove marked</button></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('todoCtrl',['$scope' ,function ($scope) {
  $scope.toDoList = [{todoText: "check", done: false}];

  $scope.toDoAdd = function () {
    $scope.toDoList.push({todoText: $scope.todoInput, done: false});
    $scope.todoInput = "";
  }
}])
```

There are two ways of using controllers, one with `$scope` and other with `controller as vm` in this case for simplicity I am using `$scope` you can read more about the other notation in [this guide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#controllers)